# Passing States with Redirect

Tags: reactjs, redirect

I am trying to pass state using Redirect and I am getting an error 'events' is not defined. I am unsure why this is the case

Component1:

```
//cal_events is an array of objects
<Redirect to={{
 pathname: '/component2', state: { events: this.state.cal_events}
}} />
```

component2:

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log('Mounted: ' + this.props.location.state.events);
}
```

I am getting the error Cannot read property 'events' of undefined

Comment: tried demo on: https://codesandbox.io/s/2o6yr46j4y should have state.events there, but you can try console.log in render function, it could be because you mounted this component before redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make use of withRouter Hoc in your second component.

If you bind the second component with withRouter HOC then you can access the location props in that component

For example:

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class MyComponent extends Component {
    ...
}

withRouter(MyComponent)
```

Comment: Thanks, can you provide an example?

Comment: @user10696040, updated the answer, please have a look and mark the answer as accepted if that solves your issue, thanks

Comment: @user10696040, will you please create a sandbox with the issue demonstration so that I can look into it.